# How can I check if a sequence of numbers is a fibonnaci sequence and obtain the next value In R?

Tags: r, math, data-manipulation

How can we create a function to do this? So given these numbers, how can we check whether they are in fact a fibonacci sequence and then predict the next value in the sequence?

1   1    2    3    5
1   2    3    5    8
2   3    5    8   13
3   5    8   13   21
5   8   13   21   34
8  13   21   34   55
13  21   34   55   89
21  34   55   89  144
34  55   89  144  233

Comment: What would you suggest, given what you know about this sequence?

Comment: @ AkselA I think the best way to solve the issue would be to have an IF statement to see if each of the elements in the sequence is the sum of the 2 elements before it and if it does we can solve the next element by adding together the last and second last elements.

Comment: so your seed is `1 1 2 3 5`?

Comment: @BethanHuish I agree: this is the best way, and what’s more, it’s elegant and efficient. Is that the answer you’re looking for?

Comment: @Manuel F, each sequence in my list of examples would be a separate input e.g fibSeq <- c(1,2,3,5,8) and then we apply the IF statement and function on fibSeq

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 4):

Your approach,

> see if each of the elements in the sequence is the sum of the 2 elements before it

Is correct and (mostly) complete. How do we transform this into code?

As always when a solution isn’t obvious, we can fix this by *decomposing* and solving individual steps, followed by combining them. This means: solve the problem for *one* element, and then *generalise* the solution. In the process, we also need to take care of edge cases.

Without further ado, here’s how to solve this for a single element at index `i` in a vector `x` (this is just a literal translation of your description into code):

```
is_fib_element = function (i, x) {
     x[i - 2L] + x[i - 1L] == x[i]
}
```

Now we need to do this for *each* element. Whenever we say “for each element” in R, this means we want to use an `*apply`. Since this is a **v**ector, we want [`vapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html). There’s a subtlety: normally we would call `vapply` directly on a vector. Instead, here we need to apply it to *indices* of our vector (`i` above).

And because we are accessing the two elements *before* the current one, we need to exclude the first two indices:

```r
indices = seq_along(x)[-(1 : 2)]
result = vapply(indices, is_fib_element, logical(1L), x)
```

This will give us a vector of `logical` values. To see whether the condition is true for *all* elements, we use [`all`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.html):

```r
all(result)
```

Furthermore, before executing the above test, we need to ensure that `x` contains at least three elements (otherwise we can’t sum two elements and compare to the third).

Putting this all together gives us this:

```r
is_fib = function (x) {
    if (length(x) < 3L) return(FALSE)

    is_fib_element = function (i, x) {
         x[i - 2L] + x[i - 1L] == x[i]
    }

    indices = seq_along(x)[-(1 : 2)]
    result = vapply(indices, is_fib_element, logical(1L), x)
    all(result)
}
```

… and we can simplify this slightly by removing unnecessary intermediate variables and by noticing that we do not need to pass `x` into the helper function, since it’s always the same `x`:

```r
is_fib = function (x) {
    if (length(x) < 3L) return(FALSE)

    is_fib_element = function (i) x[i - 2L] + x[i - 1L] == x[i]
    indices = seq_along(x)[-(1 : 2)]
    all(vapply(indices, is_fib_element, logical(1L)))
}
```

---

One final note: I said initially that this approach is only “mostly” complete. Why? Because it will return `TRUE` for the following input:

```r
is_fib(c(2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26))
```

However, while this sequence follows the rules of a Fibonacci sequence, it isn’t contained in *the* Fibonacci sequence because it is not contained in the sequence starting with 0, 1, ….

Comment: lol... and mine is "inefficient", right?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks the solution works great, in order to obtain the next value in the sequence can I do something like this: fibSolver = function (x){
  if (isTRUE(is_fib(x))){
    a<-head(x,-1);
    b<-head(x,-2);
    c <- a+b;
    return(c);
  } 
}       ?

Comment: @BethanHuish Not quite, `head` with negative numbers removes them: check `head(1 : 10, -1)`. Instead, you need `tail`: `fibSolver = function (x) { if(is_fib(x)) tail(x, 1L) + tail(x, 2L) }` Note the lack of `isTRUE` and `return`, as these aren’t necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph cheers, is there a reason why the function's returning 2 values though? The first value seems to be correct however I am not sure where the second value is coming from

Comment: @BethanHuish Because my code is wrong, oops. `tail(x, 2L)` returns the last two values, not the second-to-last value. You need to replace it by `tail(x, 2L)[1L]`, which is a bit convoluted unfortunately. R has no clean way of expressing “the n-th value from the end”, unlike e.g. Python.

Answer (score -3):

using the **numbers** package, you create a *fibonacci* series (list) as large as many numbers you want, `10` in this case:

```r
> library(numbers)
> f = fibonacci(10,TRUE)
> f
 [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
```

using the first three elements of your list as instance/example:

```r
> list = list(c(1,1,2,3,5),c(1,2,3,5,8),c(2,3,5,8,13))

> EVAL <- function(e){#e=list[[1]]
+    out = -1
+    if(length(unique(is.na(match(e,f))))==1){
+       out = f[rev(match(e,f))[1]+1]
+    }
+    return(out)
+ }
> 
> answer = lapply(list,EVAL)
> answer
[[1]]
[1] 8

[[2]]
[1] 13

[[3]]
[1] 21
```

if the input is not a fibonacci series it returns `1`.

Comment: Why the repost? This is *identical* to your earlier answer that you yourself deleted. Double-posting is not the accepted way around here. It's also quite rude towards those SO members who've left comments in response to your post. You can undelete your earlier post by clicking the undelete button below your answer.